# How to setup models in flask with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I want to use PyMongo directly within flask, is it possible to create `models.py` for MongoDB without ORMs? If so, is it recommended?

I don't know how/if possible to create `models.py` so I just work with db without it

**config.py**

```
class Config(object):
    # ...
    DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URI') or \
        'mongodb+srv://kay:myRealPassword@cluster0-wpeiv.mongodb.net/test'
```

**app/__ init __.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from pymongo import MongoClient

app = Flask(__name__)
# ...
client = MongoClient(app.config['DATABASE_URI'])
db = client.test
```

**app/routes.py**

```
# ...
from app import db

users = db.users
posts = db.posts

@app.route('/')
# ...
```

Should I just use the driver directly in my `routes.py`?

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible to do without an "ORM" (or technically an "ODM" ) like Mongoose.

However, it would certainly *not* be recommended to use your driver, or anything that indicates that you are using mongo, into routes.py. Instead, routes.py should make calls to a service layer (for example, a module or modules with all your business logic as service functions). Then your service layer should make calls to a data access layer where you can, if you like, make calls to pymongo directly.

This might not be a bad way to do things if the documents in your mongodb have widely varying structure, for which the constraints imposed by Mongoose or similar ODMs which assume a consistent schema of documents within a collection might be painful.

However if you go this route (no pun intended) then remember:

- This is no excuse to avoid layering your system and separate the concerns of routes, services, and data access.
- You will have to write your own validation functions for types, lengths, required values, etc. These kinds of validations are generally given to you for free within an ODM. Look for some validation packages that you can pip install, which should help you to avoid too much wheel invention.

Proceed carefully and with a good design and lots of tests, and this can be an acceptable architecture. However, if you have a situation in which all documents within a collection always have the same structure, there is nothing wrong with Mongoose. But it’s fine to use PyMongo directly if you have a simple app with lots of schema variation in your documents.

Comment: So I should create a separate files ex `user.py` and write all the functions that handle data access with call to pymongo driver?

Comment: Yes, a layered system is better. The routes should just call service functions. That way if you ever switch from mongo to something else, you can just edit the service layer.

Answer (score -1):

Hollo!
it takes a lot of work, and you have to reinvent the wheel
instead use an ODM like mongoengine, after you can use pymongo if you wish